# Можно ли интерпретатор Perl поставить на свой сайт?

Tags: perl

По курсовой мне необходим интерпретатор Perl, что-то даже не представлю как его написать. Есть идеи?

Comment: Вам нужно с нуля его написать? А готовые решения никак не подойдут? Ничего не понял.

Comment: готовых скриптов не видела интерпретаторов. плохо искала? ну что значит с нуля. можно не с нуля) необходимо, чтоб в окошке браузера на сайте пользователь мог ввести код программы,нажать на кнопочку, и увидеть результат своей программы. вроде разжевала достаточно подробно

Comment: Если пользуетесь сервером на домашнем компьютере, просто ставите интерпретатор перла, какой хотите (все зависит от используемой ОС). Если на стороннем сервере, то ищете хостинт с поддержкой перла, благо, таких сейчас немало. Интерпретатор перла - это не скрипт, а весьма серьезная программа.

Comment: сайт выложен на хостинг, тема курсовой обучающая система perl. есть лекции на нем,гостевая книга,система контроля знаний в виде тестов, и видеообучние. препод хочет чтобы на сайте пользователь мог набрать код, и увидеть ее результат. предполагается, что он не устанавливает activPerl и локальный сервер и еще что либо.. а прям на сайте все выполняет. вот. вы меня недопонимаете просто. можно ли это осуществить?

Comment: Так почему же нельзя. Пишите скрипт на любом языке, ПХП или том же перле, который получает текст, введенный в окошке и передает его интерпретатору перла. Можно сохранить во временный файл, путь к которому передается интерпретатору. Далее считывается вывод и передается клиенту. Как-то так в общих чертах.

Comment: На том компьютере, где Ваш сайт и соответственно Ваша программа (допустим на PHP), которая читает введенный в окошечке код на языке perl, должен быть установлен **интерпретатор perl** ( это такая программа). 

Установлен и доступен (т.е. что бы ее вызывать можно было из Вашего кода, который окошечки рисует).

Comment: Куча ответов. Но что нужно @Эля -- в тумане. Так и непонятно, то ли нужно что-то написать на перле/использовать готовый скрипт, то ли нужно написать интерпретатор крошечного подмножества перла.

Comment: alexlz алгоритм дальнейших действий примерный у меня в голове сложился, так что не волнуйся я не пропаду.

Comment: Т.е. пропащей Вы не станете -- это радует. Но всё же, что же Вам надо было? (Любопытство проклятое)

Comment: да уж, мало вещей изза которых я каким то образом стану пропащей. я же всё достаточно подробно расписала и разжевала. у меня остается месяц, так что для начала подтяну себя читая литературу,буду парралельно соображать. если уж не смогу сделать,в чем я сомневаюсь, так и придется в ифрейм кинуть

Comment: Виноват, не углядел Ваш комментарий с заданием. Если не связываться в javascript'ом -- проще. Связываться -- возможно покрасивей (трафик меньше). Успехов.

Answer (score 1):

ну дык оформляете textarea как терминал, пишете обработчик события типа execPerlSource, шлёте асинхронным запросом на сервер содержимое textarea, выполняете присланное в каком-то eval-е и возвращаете/выводите результат.
но вам же не нужно общее решение задачи, верно?

Comment: а уж сколько всего интересного можно нагуглить по запросу "perl online interpreter"... но я думаю, что гуглить - это тоже лишнее.

Comment: мне нуужно все)и за общее решение спасибо.

Comment: http://codepad.org/3F35rboD нашла онлайн интерпретатор. эх круто)

Comment: загрузи в ифрейм и скажи, что сама написала

Comment: А еще лучше покажи сайт microsoft.com и скажи, что сама написала. Годовой зачет обеспечен.

Comment: оч смешно.